# Temporary redirection of stderr in a bash script

Tags: bash, segmentation-fault, redirect, stdin, stderr

I have a simple script which is used to start another program. This other program may sometimes yield a `SIGSEGV`, which disrupts my output. I have therefore added a couple of lines which is supposed to temporarily redirect the `stderr` to `/dev/null` such that the `SIGSEGV` is ignored. The following is a draft of my code:

```
exec 2> /dev/null
progname >& ./tmp/run.txt && run_status='OK'
exec 2>1
```

The problem is that the last line does not do what I want. The first line obviously works, and redirects the `stderr`. The last line is supposed to return the `stderr` back to where it was before (which I have only supposed is the same as `stdout`).

Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: Why are you using ">&" if you don't want stderr to go to the output file?

Comment: The segmentation fault that stops the program from running is not outputted by the program itself. I do not know why this is so, but it means that I don't care about the stderr of the program (and that is why I use ">&"), but of the script itself.

Comment: Wont the signal still stop your program even though you redirect stderr to /dev/null? How can that help? either way, shouldn't you exec 2>/dev/stderr to get it back to stderr?

Comment: First: Thanks for the comment about /dev/stderr (that was actually what I wanted all along)! Second: You are right, the program will stop. The thing is: I don't care about the program, I only care about the output. I don't want to see the program errors until I open the file 'run.txt'.

Comment: I bet you if you took out that ">&" you wouldn't have to all this messing around with exec.  ">&" say to redirect stdout and stderr into the file.  If you just used ">", stdout would go to the file and stderr would go to the screen.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want stderr to go to the screen. I want stderr to go to the file, and with I achieve this with ">&".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another option is:

```
exec 3> /dev/stderr 2> /dev/null
progname >& ./tmp/run.txt && run_status='OK'
exec 2>&3
```

Or even

```
exec 3>&2 2> /dev/null
progname >& ./tmp/run.txt && run_status='OK'
exec 2>&3
```

That way the script preserves the separation of stdout and stderr for the script (ie. the scripts stdout and stderr can be redirected separately.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just redirect it for the progname run only?

```
   progname > ./tmp/run.txt 2>/dev/null && run_status='OK'
```

Or possibly

```
{
   progname > ./tmp/run.txt && run_status='OK'
} 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: That would have been a solution if it was the program itself which sent the error message to stderr. This is not the case, probably because when the program is interrupted by a SIGSEGV it stops before being able to output an error message. It is therefore redirected to the parent process.

Comment: I think you don't know what you're talking about.  Either the program outputs to stderr, or it doesn't.  There is no "redirected to the parent process".

Comment: Ah, sorry. I do not know what I am talking about, no. But I know that the program stops with a segmentation fault, and that it does not output to stderr. Also. the "parent process" (or what I should call it) is the one that outputs the segmentation fault to screen.